# How can I use local objective-c framework in my Swift Pod

Tags: objective-c, swift, frameworks, cocoapods

I have Swift pod which need objective-c framework.

`MyClass.swift` which need `XXX.framework` (objective-c framework)

My file structure

```
-MyClass.swift
-XXX.framework
-Bridging-Header.h
```

podspec

```
s.frameworks = 'XXX'
s.preserve_paths = 'Frameworks/*.framework'
s.vendored_frameworks = 'Frameworks/XXX.framework'
s.xcconfig = { 'SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER' => '${POD_ROOT}/POD_NAME/Bridging-Header.h' }
```

When I try `pod install` I get this error.

```
<unknown>:0: error: using bridging headers with framework targets is unsupported
```

I don't sure this is possible with cocoapods and don't sure what I did is the right way. Could you guide me to right direction?